# Error in firebase.getCurrentUser: Error: java.lang.Exception: Failed resolving method getToken on class com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

This is when i call
`user.getToken()`
Everything else works fine(email, name, photo, etc..)

```
      dependencies {
          // make sure you have these versions by updating your local Android SDK's (Android Support repo and Google repo)
          compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.4.0"
          compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-database:9.4.0"
          compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.4.0"
          compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:9.4.0"

          // for reading google-services.json and configuration
          compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:9.4.0"

          // Uncomment if you want to use 'Remote Config'
           compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-config:9.4.0"

          // Uncomment if you want FCM (Firebase Cloud Messaging)
           compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.4.0"

          // Uncomment if you want Google Cloud Storage
           compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:9.4.0'

          // Uncomment if you need Facebook Authentication
           compile "com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.+"

          // Uncomment if you need Google Sign-In Authentication
           compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9.4.0"

      }
```

I am using https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/nativescript-plugin-firebase but getToken works in IOS(as i have been told). Problem persists only in android.

Original thread: https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/nativescript-plugin-firebase/issues/153

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was `getToken` is now `getToken(forceRefresh:boolean)`, so that explains the error (the signature is incorrect).

Furthermore, the Firebase auth token cannot be retrieved synchronously so to not further delay resolving the promise I've now added a new function to the plugin API: `getAuthToken` which returns a promise containing only the Firebase auth token which you can fi. send to your backend server to leverage the authenticated user.

```
firebase.getAuthToken({
  forceRefresh: false
}).then(
  function (token) {
    console.log("Auth token retrieved: " + token);
  },
  function (errorMessage) {
    console.log("Auth token retrieval error: " + errorMessage);
  }
);
```

See the GitHub issue for release info.